# account list as radio button options in VF page

Tags: visualforce, javascript, standardcontroller, table, radio-button

I have the below VF page where I am trying to list the account and contact details as radio button options:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" recordSetVar="accounts">
    <apex:form >



<apex:pageBlock title="Account List" id="account_list">


<table>
  <apex:repeat value="{!accounts }" var="acc">
    <tr> 
      <td>
       <apex:selectRadio layout="pageDirection">
      <apex:selectOptions value="{!acc.Name}"/>
      </apex:selectRadio >
      </td>
    </tr>
  </apex:repeat>
</table>


<h1> Contacts</h1>

<table>
  <apex:repeat value="{!accounts }" var="acc">
    <tr> 
      <apex:repeat value="{!acc.Contacts}" var="cont">
      <td><apex:outputText value="{!cont.Name}"/></td>
      </apex:repeat>
    </tr>
  </apex:repeat>
</table>


</apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

When I preview I get an error which says Invalid selectOptions found. Use SelectOption type in Apex. I would like to display the list of account and I should I able to use radio button to select a particular account. How can achieve this?

Comment: Isn't this a standard controller - Account?

Answer (score 2):

You may need to create a SelectOption list using a controller extension, something like this:

```
public List<SelectOption> getItems() {
  List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>(); 
  for (Account a : myAccountsList) {
    options.add(new SelectOption(a.Id, a.Name))
  }

  return options; 
}
```

Then you add the options to your `<apex:selectRadio>` tag thusly:

```
<apex:selectRadio>
  <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}" />
</apex:selectRadio>
```

See also the documentation on [apex:selectRadio](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_selectRadio.htm).

Comment: Thank you so much. can you let me know where do you get myAccountslist from ? in (Account a : myAccountsList)

Comment: You'll need to query the Account object for the records. Take a look at the sample code in the apex:selectRadio documentation - it has an example for contacts, you can modify it to query account instead.

Comment: Wouldn't it come from the `StandardSetController.getSelected()` results?

Comment: Thanks. I works now! Only thing is all the accounts appears in a single row instead of appearing as list. I think its something to do with the table : Here is the code : <table>
<tr>
Accounts
<td>
<apex:selectRadio >
<apex:selectOptions value="{!items}" />
</apex:selectRadio>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

Comment: Take a look at the 'layout' attribute on <apex:selectRadio>. As I mentioned in another comment (I think on your related question), <apex:selectRadio> renders the radio buttons in a table. The 'layout' attribute allows you to run them vertically.

Answer (score 1):

To make a `selectRadio` work without extensions, you need to build out `SelectOption` markup.

```
<apex:selectRadio>
    <apex:repeat value="{!accounts}" var="account">
        <apex:selectOption itemValue="{!account.Id}" itemLabel="{!account.Name}" />
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:selectRadio>
```

Comment: I get this error - Select components should have at least one child component of type selectOption or selectOptions

Comment: It appears as radio button when you do not use repeat tag in between selectRadio and SelectOption tag. But I am able to check all the radio button(accounts) at the one time, I guess I should only be able to check one account at a time since its a radio button. Correct?